# v-model cannot be used on v-for

Tags: eslint, vuejs3

VueCompilerError: v-model cannot be used on v-for or v-slot scope variables because they are not writable. Why?

```
<template>
  <div v-for="service in services" :key="service.id">
    <ServicesItem v-model="service"></ServicesItem >
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import ServicesItem from "@js/components/ServicesItem.vue"

export default defineComponent({
  components: { ServicesItem },
  setup() {
    const services = ref([
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Service 1",
        active: false,
        types_cars: {
          cars: {},
          suv: {},
        },
      },
    ])

    return {
      services,
    }
  },
})
</script>
```

What are the best practices? Reactive object transfers

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Okay, so what's going on is that the variable "service" is, let's say, virtual.
It doesn't exist, it's just a part of your real object "services" at a certain point (iteration).

If you'd like to "attach" that iteration to your component, you need to provide a **real** object, and in your case that would be done like that:

```
<div v-for="(service, i) in services" :key="service.id">
    <ServicesItem v-model="services[i]"></ServicesItem >
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here, i've change the `modelValue` props by an other custom props, and it works fine for me.
old:

```
const props = defineProps({
    modelValue: {
        type: Object,
        required: true
    }
})
```

NEW:

```
const props = defineProps({
    field: {
        type: Object,
        required: true
    }
})
```

Component:
`<MyComponent :field="service"/>`

instead of
`<MyComponent :v-model="service"/>`